# Function that self destructs

Tags: r, function, quine

I read some post where Hadley made a joke about a self destructing function. I thought this would be relatively simple to implement but turns out it's not.

Here is an attempt to write a function named `self_delete` that is a quine and attempts to self destruct after printing its body. The idea was to search for the function's name in `.GlobalEnv` and delete it but that doesn't work. I would like to understand why this is the case.

```
self_delete<- function(){
   print(body(self_delete))
   rm(list=lsf.str(pattern="self_delete"))
 }
```

Calling the above prints the following as expected but does not delete itself from `.Globalenv`, what am I missing? I did try with `rm` and `ls` too with no luck

```
 self_delete()
{
    print(body(self_delete))
    rm(list = lsf.str(pattern = "self_delete"))
}
```

Comment: Won't `rm(list = 'self_delete')` do it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't and I'm not sure why. It actually warns that `self_delete` is not found.

Comment: `rm(list = 'self_delete', envir = .GlobalEnv)`?

Comment: @Sotos Yes, you are missing the `envir` argument: `rm(list = "self_delete", envir = .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: Oh woow, thanks. I forgot all about the calling environment.

Comment: @RuiBarradas ahhh...yes. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to set the `envir` argument to `rm()`, so it's trying to delete `self_delete` from the calling frame, not from `globalenv()`.

This works:

```
self_delete <- function(){
  print(body(self_delete))
  rm("self_delete", envir = globalenv())
}
```